# CodeIgniter Load More Comment Result

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

anyone can help me to make load more or doing pagenation for the comment result of the topic content?. This is how it it works my topic content call the query using the slug now I want the topic content reply show by **pagenation** or via **load more button**

My topic content **controller**:

```
 public function topic($slug = NULL) {

        // get single topic
        $data['item'] = $this->topic_model->getTopic($slug);
        if(empty($data['item'])) {
            $data['title'] = lang_key('404errorheader');
            $data['desc'] = lang_key('404errordesc');
            $this->load->view('themes/default/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('errors/html/error_404');
            $this->load->view('themes/default/footer');
        }else{ 

        $data['title'] = $data['item']['title'];
        $data['desc'] = strip_tags(word_limiter($data['item']['content'],30));

        $this->load->view('themes/default/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('threads/topic', $data);
        $this->load->view('themes/default/footer');
        $this->add_view($slug);
        }
    }
```

and my topic content **model**:

```
 // get single topic
    public function getTopic($slug) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('threads', array('thread_slug'=>$slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

and my topic reply **helper**:

```
//get topic reply
if ( ! function_exists('get_topic_reply'))
{
    function get_topic_reply($topic_id)
    {

        $CI = get_instance();
        $CI->load->database();

        $CI->db->order_by('id', 'asc');
        $CI->db->where('topic_id',$topic_id);
        $CI->db->where('status',1);
        $query = $CI->db->get_where('threads_comment');
        return $query;

    }
}
```

This is how I display the result. **mydomain/topic/topic-slug**
Content of the topic data is the topic content calling the query using slug and I only include the content reply via:

```
<?php require('topicreply.php');?>
```

The codes of this **topicreply.php**:

```
                                   <?php 
                                    $topic_id = (isset($topic_id))?$topic_id:$item['id'];
                                    $topicreply = get_topic_reply($topic_id); 
                                    $i=0;
                                    foreach($topicreply->result() as $toprep):
                                    $i++;
                                    ?>

                                    <!-- .reply -->
                                    <div id="post-797" class="bbp-reply-header">
                                        <div class="bbp-meta">
                                            <span class="bbp-reply-permalink pull-right text-danger"><?php echo lang_key('reply'),' #'.$i ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- .bbp-meta -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- #post-797 -->
                                    <div class="even topic-author hentry">
                                        <div class="bbp-reply-author">
                                            <a href="#" class="bbp-author-avatar">
                                                <img src="<?php echo get_profile_photo_by_id($toprep->user_id); ?>" class="avatar photo" alt="<?php echo get_user_title_by_id($toprep->user_id);?>" height="80" width="80">
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="#" class="bbp-author-name <?php echo get_user_type_by_id_name(get_user_role_by_id($toprep->user_id));?>"><?php echo get_user_title_by_id($toprep->user_id);?></a>
                                            <div class="bbp-author-role"><?php echo get_user_type_by_id(get_user_role_by_id($toprep->user_id));?></div>
                                            <div class="bbp-reply-post-date"><?php 
                                            $post_date = $toprep->created_at;
                                            $now = time();
                                            echo timespan($post_date, $now, 1).'&nbsp'.lang_key('ago'); ?>.</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- .bbp-reply-author -->
                                        <div class="bbp-reply-content">
                                            <p><?php echo str_replace('href=', 'rel="nofollow" href=',$toprep->comment_content); ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- .bbp-reply-content -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- .reply -->
                                    <?php endforeach ?>
```

I want the result in topicreply.php will not display all instead there will be a load more button or pagenation. Anyone can help me? Ive been looking on the Internet but I cant find similar to my problem.

**Note:** The codes is working fine and no problem at all its only, I want the topic reply/comment can be view some of the reply via pagenation or loadmore!

Comment: This is *not* a code writing service, show what you have done to implement a pagination/loadmore system. `https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html`

Comment: Thanks I`ll recoding this one again thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its working now but instead of Load More I use pagination. Here the code in my controller

```
// category
    public function threadsview($slug=null, $offset=0) {
        // get threads category
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $data['item'] = $this->threads_model->getThreadsCategory($slug);
        if($data['item']->num_rows()<=0){
            $data['title'] = lang_key('404errorheader');
            $data['desc'] = lang_key('404errordesc');
            $this->load->view('themes/default/layout/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('errors/html/error_404');
            $this->load->view('themes/default/layout/footer');
        }else
        foreach ($data['item']->result() as $res) {


        $data['title'] = $res->catname;
        $data['desc'] = $res->description;

        $cat_id = get_category_id_by_slug($slug);
        $total = 10; // total result x page

        // Config setup
        $num_rows = $this->threads_model->getAllThreadsPost($cat_id); // get all threads post per category
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'threadsview/'.$slug;
        $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
        $config['per_page'] = $total;
        $config['num_links'] = $num_rows;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';

        if ($this->input->get('page') != null) {
            $offset = ($this->input->get('page') - 1) * $config['per_page'];
        }

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['threads_post'] = $this->threads_model->AllThreadsPost($cat_id, $config['per_page'], $offset);

        $this->load->view('themes/default/layout/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('threads/threadsview', $data);
        $this->load->view('themes/default/layout/footer');
        }
    }
```

But I have another concern I hope someone can help me. The result numbering is my problem. As you can see the pagination will display 10 results every page but my result numbering once you go to second page instead the number will goes to 11 to 20 it will return to 1-10. Look the codes below

```
<?php if(count($threads_post) > 0){ ?>
                                                <?php 
                                                $i = 0;
                                                foreach($threads_post as $threads): 
                                                $i++;?>
```